# Keep div inside Container

Tags: html, css

I've the snippet below, and if you look into it then you can see that the lowest level of items is outside the container.

I know its because of the `position:absolute; transform:translate(-33%)`.
But it's the only way so far i've been able to center the elements below the it's parrent.

Is the some way to "put" the 3 lowest elements into the container and make the whole thing scroll able from left to right?

```css
body {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 2000px
}

.CB {
  background-color: #c4cfd8;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.CB .CB_Menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts {
  text-align: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div > div {
  display: inline-table;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span a {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content {
  text-align: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img {
  width: 100%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop {
  height: 25px;
  width: calc(100% - 25%);
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-left: 1px dotted #fff;
  margin: 0 110px;
  display: none;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.none {
  border-right: none;
  width: 1px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.two {
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop .LineTop_Line {
  width: 219px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom {
  display: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line.Test {
  width: calc(50% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="CB">

  <div class="CB_Menu">
    header
  </div>

  <div class="CB_Content">

    <div class="Products">
      <div>
        <div class="Product">
          <div class="Product_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Product_Content">
            <div class="Product_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Product_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Product_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineBottom active">
          <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Parts">
      <div>
        <div class="lineTop active">
          <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
          <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="Part">
            <div class="Part_Header">
              <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content">
              <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Content_right">
                <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Footer">
              <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="position:absolute; transform:translate(-33%)">
            <div class="lineBottom active">
              <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="sub_part">
              <div class="lineTop active">
                <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="Parts">
                <div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to solve this but your CSS is really messed up :/

Comment: @ZombieChowder why is it messed up?

Comment: I kinda understand what you need. Remove the `width: 1200px` from the `.CB` selector. this will fill your page with the container and scroll left and right....NEVERMIND. Body has a 2000px width...

Comment: The body width doesn't matter if the main container which has the elements has a fixed width. The nodes will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this?  Changes that you have to make:

- Remove the fixed width of body i.e width:2000px.
- Remove the fixed width of CB class i.e width:1200px.

You can set the width to auto or leave them be and they will expand horizontally as needed.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.CB {
  background-color: #c4cfd8;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.CB .CB_Menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts {
  text-align: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div > div {
  display: inline-table;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span a {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content {
  text-align: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img {
  width: 100%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop {
  height: 25px;
  width: calc(100% - 25%);
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-left: 1px dotted #fff;
  margin: 0 110px;
  display: none;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.none {
  border-right: none;
  width: 1px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.two {
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop .LineTop_Line {
  width: 219px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom {
  display: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line.Test {
  width: calc(50% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="CB">

  <div class="CB_Menu">
    header
  </div>

  <div class="CB_Content">

    <div class="Products">
      <div>
        <div class="Product">
          <div class="Product_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Product_Content">
            <div class="Product_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Product_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Product_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lineBottom active">
          <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Parts">
      <div>
        <div class="lineTop active">
          <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
          <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="Part">
            <div class="Part_Header">
              <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content">
              <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Content_right">
                <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Footer">
              <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div style="position:absolute; transform:translate(-33%)">
            <div class="lineBottom active">
              <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="sub_part">
              <div class="lineTop active">
                <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="Parts">
                <div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Part">
                    <div class="Part_Header">
                      <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Content">
                      <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part_Content_right">
                        <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Part_Footer">
                      <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Part">
          <div class="Part_Header">
            <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Content">
            <div class="Part_Content_Left">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="Part_Content_right">
              <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="Part_Footer">
            <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scroll down and see, yes they are and before that try to run it at full page before rating it down.

Comment: No i want to keep the CB width of 1200

Comment: @PeterHansen Your 1200px is what is causing the elements to go out or overflow the container since its not enough. You have to modify the nodes to have % width rather than fixed px width if you want them inside your fixed 1200 CB container.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    body {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 2000px
}

.CB {
  background-color: #c4cfd8;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.CB .CB_Menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts {
  text-align: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products > div > div,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts > div > div {
  display: inline-table;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Header span a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Header span a {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content {
  text-align: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_Left a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Product_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Content .Part_Content_right img {
  width: 100%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer a,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Product_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Product .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Products .Part .Part_Footer button,
.CB .CB_Content .Parts .Part .Part_Footer button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #000;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop {
  height: 25px;
  width: calc(100% - 17%);
  border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  border-left: 1px dotted #fff;
  margin: 0 110px;
  display: none;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.none {
  border-right: none;
  width: 1px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop.two {
  width: calc(100% - 50%);
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineTop .LineTop_Line {
  width: 219px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
  float: left;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom {
  display: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 115%;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom.active {
  display: block;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #fff;
}

.CB .CB_Content .lineBottom .LineBottom_Line.Test {
  width: calc(50% - 300px);
}

.sub_part{ width: 445px; }
    </style>     




    <div class="CB">

      <div class="CB_Menu">
        header
      </div>

      <div class="CB_Content">

        <div class="Products">
          <div>
            <div class="Product">
              <div class="Product_Header">
                <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="Product_Content">
                <div class="Product_Content_Left">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="Product_Content_right">
                  <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Product_Footer">
                <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lineBottom active">
              <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Parts">
          <div>
            <div class="lineTop active">
              <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
              <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="Part">
                <div class="Part_Header">
                  <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="Part_Content">
                  <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Part_Content_right">
                    <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Part_Footer">
                  <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div style="position:absolute; transform:translate(-33%)">
                <div class="lineBottom active">
                  <div class="LineBottom_Line"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="sub_part">
                  <div class="lineTop active">
                    <div class="LineTop_Line"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Parts">
                    <div>
                      <div class="Part">
                        <div class="Part_Header">
                          <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Content">
                          <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Part_Content_right">
                            <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Footer">
                          <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part">
                        <div class="Part_Header">
                          <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Content">
                          <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Part_Content_right">
                            <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Footer">
                          <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="Part">
                        <div class="Part_Header">
                          <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Content">
                          <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="Part_Content_right">
                            <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Part_Footer">
                          <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="Part">
              <div class="Part_Header">
                <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Content">
                <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="Part_Content_right">
                  <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Footer">
                <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Part">
              <div class="Part_Header">
                <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Content">
                <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="Part_Content_right">
                  <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Footer">
                <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Part">
              <div class="Part_Header">
                <span>Title<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></span>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Content">
                <div class="Part_Content_Left">
                  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="Part_Content_right">
                  <img src="https://www.maltbazaren.dk/images/staal-300x300-t.png" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Part_Footer">
                <button>Show <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: .just adjust width of sub_part section.

Comment: Tarun now the sub_part is not centered below the parent

Comment: Yes i know but you don't want to increase the width of container.

Comment: If you want to keep a fixed width of the container CB like I mentioned in my answer, your only alternative is change the width of the nodes to a smaller size of relative % size and you have to code the CSS styles for your lines again with relation to the new node sizes. Or else, you will have to stick with auto width of the container.

Comment: .part{ width : 175px; height : 190px } & .sub_part{ width : 593px;}